# All new users created in array not showing

Tags: php, arrays

Im creating a registration site, im having a hard time implementing the loop in the new users created array. Logging in to admin shows all the users created(new ones) in (registration.php). In my case, it is just showing the the recent user created. Is there a solution to show all of the them?

```
        **LoginValidator.php**
        <?php
        session_start();
        $newUsers=array();
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $_SESSION['counter']; $i++ ){
                for($i = 0; $i <= $_SESSION['counter']; $i++ ){
                    $newUsers[] = array("User"=> $_SESSION["userName"], "Password"=> $_SESSION["fpassWord"]); 
                }
            }

        //admin
        $users=array(
            array("User"=> "admin" , "Password"=>"admin"),

        );
            $userName = $_GET['username'];
            $msg = "";

            foreach ($users as $value) {
                if ($userName == $value['User'] && $_GET['password'] == $value['Password']) {
                    echo "<p>Login successful<3</p>";
                    
                    print_r(array_merge($users,$newUsers));
                    
                } else if ($userName == $value["User"] and $_GET['password'] != $value["Password"]) {
                    $msg = "<p>Wrong Password</p>";
                    
                } 
            }
            echo $msg;
         ?>



**Registration.php**
        <?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
        $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['create'])){
        $_SESSION["userName"] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION["fpassWord"] = $_POST['fpassword'];
        $_SESSION["rpassWord"] = $_POST['rpassword'];
        $_SESSION["firstName"] = $_POST['firstname'];
        $_SESSION["lastName"] = $_POST['lastname'];
        $_SESSION["eMail"] = $_POST['email'];
        ++$_SESSION['counter'];



        if ($_POST["fpassword"] === $_POST["rpassword"]) {
        echo "Session data stored Login now <br>";
        echo $_SESSION['counter'];
         }
         else {
            echo "Password not the same!";
         }
    }
    else{
        echo "Create not set";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: As an aside, the session is a very odd place to store user information. A session is a temporary store for a single user, but user registrations generally need to be permanent and the same for all users, so would usually be in some kind of database on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you assign to a variable, the old value is overwritten, so every time you write `$_SESSION["userName"] = $_POST['username'];` you are keeping only the current username.

Later, you have two `for` loops, both trying to set `$i`, but they don't actually do anything different on each iteration, they just repeatedly read that same variable. If the counter is 3, you will get 9 copies of it (3 times round the outer loop, and 3 times round the inner loop each time).

If you want there to be multiple users in the session, you have to put them there, e.g. in an array:

```
$key = $_SESSION['counter'];
$_SESSION['newUsers'][$key] = [];
$_SESSION['newUsers'][$key]["userName"] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['newUsers'][$key]["fpassWord"] = $_POST['fpassword'];
// etc
++$_SESSION['counter'];
```